Does every product of copies of $\mathbb Z$ fail to be pseudocompact?
A space is pseudocompact if every continuous image of the space into $\mathbb R$ is bounded.
Clearly $\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb R$ is not pseudocompact, as inclusion is in unbounded continuous mapping.
Likewise $\mathbb Z^\omega$ is not pseudocompact, as it is a copy of the irrationals $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, and we can again look to inclusion.
Is there an argument to show that any product of copies of $\mathbb Z$ fails to be pseudocompact?

Note that if $S$ is any (nonempty) set then there is a continuous projection map $\pi_1 : \mathbb{Z}^S \to \mathbb{Z}$. Let $\iota:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the inclusion map, also continuous. Then $\iota \circ \pi_1$ is continuous with unbounded image. So no power of $\mathbb{Z}$ is pseudocompact.

Nice. So more generally, this argument shows that if an arbitrary (non-empty) product of spaces is pseudocompact, every factor is pseudocompact.  Not sure about the other direction.

I vaguely recall there being a pseudocompact whose square is not pseudocompact. I also think I recall that the product of a pseudocompact and countably compact space is pseudocompact.

@StevenClontz: a chase starting at the Wikipedia page on pseudo-compactness got me to this paper: Novak, On the cartesian product of two compact spaces, Fund. Math. vol. 40 (1953) pp.
106-112. which gives an example of a product of two (non-Hausdorff) compact spaces, whose product is not compact. I think that may be the counter-example you had in mind.

In that paper, "bicompact" is used to mean what is normally called compact, while "compact" is used to mean what is normally called countably compact.

In Engelking, 3.10.19, two countably compact subspaces of $\beta \mathbb N$ (hence completely regular, $T_2$ are described, whose product is not pseudo-compact (see remark preceding 3.10.26).

In fact, in my above-mentioned example, Engelking refers to the paper mentioned by @Rob Arthan. Therefore, I would expect that these spaces are Hausdorff. (And, of course, in modern terminology, countably compact, not compact.)
